# jquery keyup on drop down list

Tags: jquery, html-select, keyup

When an element from the list is selected I want to fill the search input with the 'data-search' attribute.

I have this markup:

```
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" id="id_search" />
    <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                    <option value="-1" selected>Choose your prize</option>
                    <option value="1" class="search-btn" data-search="camera">Camera</option>
                    <option value="2" class="search-btn" data-search="diamonds">Diamonds</option>
                    <option value="3" class="search-btn" data-search="spaceship">Spaceship</option>

                </select>
```

L.E: I've found a solution :

```
  $("#cd-dropdown").change(function()
  {
 $("#id_search").val($("#cd-dropdown :selected").attr("data-search"));
  });
```

but unfortunately is not working with jquery 1.8.3 is there any way to make it work with this version?

Comment: What do you expect to happen on keyup?

Comment: If you say _"not working"_ then we can't understand what could be the problem and we can only say _"best of luck, make it work soon"_. :)

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question with what I expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind an click event to the `option` element.
If i get you right you want to trigger the event, when an option has been selected. Try the following:

```
$("#cd-dropdown").change(function()
{
  $("#id_search").val($(this).data("search"));
  $("#id_search").keyup();
})
```

Comment: I've tried this but is not working, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2A64P/)

Answer (score 1):

The code "isn't working" because, according to your snippet, you don't have a button/clickable element there with the class `search-btn`. If you amend the jQuery selector to use the right class or identifier then the click event will be handled.

As for the keyup not working, I can't vouch for this because I can't see what you even expect it to do in this case - you're calling to event handler for the button but talk about it on the dropdown list, which makes your question pretty much senseless.

Comment: When an element from the list is selected I want to fill the search input with the 'data-search' attribute.
here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2A64P/) with what I'm trying.